# Respond to touches on programmatically generated custom UIButtons inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a UIScrollView full of custom UIButtons that are generated programmatically. 
This code executes every iteration through the loop, typically 7 times.

```
[cardButton
      addTarget:self
      action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cardButton setTag:i + 100];
[self.scrollView addSubview:cardButton];
```

Elsewhere I have this function:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
}
```

How do I link the two? My button actually stores all the information I need from it inside its label so I really just need to detect when it is being tapped so I can respond.

Comment: The question it's not clear. buttonPressed is not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already linked two with this line

```
[cardButton
      addTarget:self
      action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Sender is returning the instance of button which you pressed.so

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
            //Action for button with tag 1
            break;
        case 2:
            //Action for button with tag 2
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```